# Share variables from Jupyter notebook to python script

Tags: python, flask

I want to automatically share variables from a jupyter notebook (jupyter lab) to a running python script (local flask server).

For example, in my Jupyter cells, I generate via processing a Pandas DataFrame, which I can find in my Flask web page by reloading the page on my browser.

In fact, I would like to have a particular presentation of my DataFrames on which I work.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-render-pandas-dataframe-as-html-table/

Comment: ok, thanks, indeed I will need this .to_html() function, but I need to get the DataFrame variable in my flask server